# Hapijs: Not running at local host

Tags: hapi.js

[Here is my server](http://ACA80187.ipt.aol.com:3000),

Can anybody suggest me how can i run it on localhost?

This is my server.js file code

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Path = require('path');
var server = new Hapi.Server({connections: {
routes: {
    files: {
        relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname,'public')
    }
  }
 }});
 server.connection({ port: 3000 });
 var mongoose = require("mongoose");
  var routes = require('./Routes/Route');


 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
     console.log("We are connected");
   }
});

 server.views({
  engines: {
      html: require('handlebars')
  },
   path: Path.join(__dirname,'/Html')
});

 server.route(routes);

 server.start(function () {
   console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

To run your server only on localhost and not accepting external requests, you can set the `host` field within the `server.connection` configuration. Like this:

```
server.connection({  
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3000
})
```

This tutorial helps you to get a basic hapi server started just on localhost :)

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-get-your-server-up-and-running

Answer (score 0):

With a few modifications to your code I was able to start up your server with no problem. I removed the routes and just ensured that the server started and that I could at least get a 404 from the server. All of which I accomplished.

If you are concerned about what you have printing out to the console, that is because that is Hapi's attempt at finding your machine's public hostname. See this [documentation](http://hapijs.com/api#serverconnectionoptions).

Now if you would like to prevent all external traffic from your hitting your server, you will need to set the `address` in the `server.connection` function call.

It'll look like this:

```
server.connection({ port: 3000, address: '127.0.0.1' });
```